# How to map 2 nested lists to the same key in dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two nested lists:

```
list1: [[1,2,3],[4,6],[44,77,86]]
list2: [[1,3],[4,6],[44,77,86],[65]]
```

How can I map them such that we will have each lists in those big two lists a key, which will be exactly the same key in the other lists?

```
dic1: [{0,[1,2,3]},{1,[4,6]},{2,[44,77,86]}]
dic1: [{4,[1,3]},{1,[4,6]},{2,[44,77,86]},{3,[65]}]
```

You can see that the two lists in the middle of each of the two big lists are the same - therefore, they have the same key in the dictionaries.

Comment: In the last O/P: `dic1: [{4,[1,3]},{1,[4,6]},{2,[44,77,86]},{3,[65]}]` - How is `{4,[1,3]}` obtained? Can you clarify? Should it not be - `dic1: [{0,[1,3]},{1,[4,6]},{2,[44,77,86]},{3,[65]}]` ??

Comment: Your output is not a valid python expression. Did you mean `{0:[1,2,3], 1:[4,6],2:[44,77,86]}`?

Comment: @j1-lee it is valid, but it's list of sets not dict

Comment: You could build up a lookup dict whose keys are your nested lists (converted to tuples) whose values are the index (order that you've added it).  Then use that lookup to assign indices to the two dictionaries when you process them.

Comment: @sudden_appearance `{0,[1,2,3]}` isn't valid, since `[1,2,3]` is not hashable.

Comment: Why does `[1,3]` get the key `4`? Shouldn't it get `3` since it occurs before `[65]`? Or does order not matter?

Comment: @Hariharan They're saying they want the sublists to be assigned to the same keys in different dicts. Although, the details are not very clear; see the other comments here.

Comment: Do the sublists always contain hashable elements?

Comment: You have `dic1` twice. The second one should be `dic2`, no?

Answer (score 0):

`dic1` is not a legal python object. but if you want to achieve the same logic:

First, let's give an index or every list in list1:

```
lookup_table = {}
for key, l in enumerate(list1):
    lookup_table[tuple(l)] = key

# lookup_table = {(1, 2, 3): 0, (4, 6): 1, (44, 77, 86): 2}
```

Note that lookup_table is actually dic1.

Now, let's build dic2:

```
dict2 = {}
counter = len(list1)


for key, l in enumerate(list2):
    if tuple(l) in lookup_table:
        dict2[tuple(l)] = lookup_table[tuple(l)]
    else:
        dict2[tuple(l)] = counter
        counter += 1

# dic2 = {(1, 3): 3, (4, 6): 1, (44, 77, 86): 2, (65,): 4}
```

I assume that if the list doesn't exists in list1, the key is some counter.

If you want to get the mapping in dictionary of lists, you can convert dic2:

```
dic2 = [{key: list(l)} for l, key in dict2.items()]
# dic2 = [{3: [1, 3]}, {1: [4, 6]}, {2: [44, 77, 86]}, {4: [65]}]
```

and the same for dic1.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a lookup table. You can directly check the duplications with list1 :

```
list1 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 6], [44, 77, 86]]
list2 = [[1, 3], [4, 6], [44, 77, 86], [65]]


dict1 = {}
for key, l in enumerate(list1):
    dict1[key] = l

n = len(list1)
dict2 = {}
for l in list2:
    if l in list1:
        dict2[list1.index(l)] = l
    else:
        dict2[n] = l
        n += 1
```

I think that's the simplest solution